# Laravel directories for CSS, images, music files and others

Tags: css, image, laravel, view

As a Laravel newbie I have red the documentation on laravel.com. So far I really don't know where to create directories for my CSS files, image files, music files etc. I think it should be in the public directory, but not sure. As last question, how can I include those files in views within Laravel framework?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you add any CSS, JavaScript, image, etc. files to your public folder.

```
| app
| public /
     css/
     images/
     js/
```

Now if you wanted to easily use an image from within your view, you simply use Laravel's `HTML` facade, like so

```
{{ HTML::image('images/name-of-image.png'); }}
```

If you want to include a css stylesheet, then you would again use the `HTML` facade.

```
{{ HTML::style('css/styles.css') }}
```

Here is a list of Laravel's html helpers, http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/generating-html-using-html-methods